# Extend a matrix by interpolating zeros

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to implement a python code to extend a matrix in such a way as given below:

Given Matrix:

```
1 2
3 4
```

Now I want to convert it to the following:

```
1 0 0 2 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
3 0 0 4 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I am trying the same for a matrix of the dimensions 60x80. I tried out numpy.insert(). But for larger matrix I am not able to apply the same thing(as it becomes too much hardcoding). So need some suggestions to do such interpolation.

Comment: How are you getting the output exactly? Are you creating 3x3 blocks for each number or what?

Comment: Also, show what you did with insert.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `step` part of the slice to achieve this, if you preallocate yourself a result

```
repeat = 3
result = np.zeros((arr.shape[0]*repeat, arr.shape[1]*repeat))
result[::repeat,::repeat] = arr
```